# SQLite: Insufficient parameters supplied

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to store information that user entering (Like a registration) and I get an error says:

> SQLiteException was unhandled
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occured in System.Data.SQLite.dll
> Additional information: unknown error
> Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

The code:

```
var command = "insert into Reports(sReportNo, sReportDate) values(@ReportNo, @ReportDate)";
using (IDbConnection = new SQLiteConnection connection =
    new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=.\T.Server.db;Initial Catalog=Reports;Version=3;"))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Execute(command, new
    {
        sReportNo = ReportNo,
        sReportDate = ReportDate
    });
    MessageBox.Show(successful);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox(unsuccessful);
}

Reset();
```

Comment: Are there any other fields in the table? which are mandatory?

Comment: @viveknuna -  I am using SQLite DB Browser, the code over there is:
CREATE TABLE "Reports" (
"sReportNo" TEXT,
"sReportDate" TEXT
);

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
With Dapper you can send the parameters to the database as an anonymous object, like this:

```cs
var sql = "Insert into Reports (sReportNo, sReportData) values (@ReportNo, @ReportDate)";

using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=.\T.Server.db;Initial Catalog=Reports;Version=3;"))
{
    connection.Execute(sql, new {ReportNo = reportNo, ReportDate = reportDate} );
}
```

Notes:
1. I'm still guessing the variable names that holds the values.
2. Dapper will open the connection for you if it's not already open.

---

**Original answer**
You're executing the statement but you're not providing the parameters... between the `new SQLiteCommand(...)` and the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` you should add the parameters to the command:

```
using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=.\T.Server.db;Initial Catalog=Reports;Version=3;"))
{
    using(var command = new SQLiteCommand("Insert into Reports (sReportNo, sReportData) values (@ReportNo, @ReportDate)", connection)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@ReportNo", SQLiteType.Int32).Value = reportNumber;
        command.Parameters.Add("@ReportDate", SQLiteType.DateTime).Value = reportDate;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. I'm guessing the parameter types and the variable names that holds the values.
2. You only need to open the connection before executing the command.
3. You don't need to explicitly close the connection, it gets disposed (and closed) at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: It gives me few errors:
1. Cannot Initialize type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEumerable'
2.The name 'command' does not exist in the current context.
3. The name 'SQLiteType' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: My code doesn't use collection initializer. You've  copied it wrong.

Comment: Well that's not helping at all. I can't help you if you're that vague. I need to know the bare minimum here. If you could paste the entire method to the question, that might help.

Comment: Hey, I am using SQLite and Dapper so I should to use the correct syntax

Comment: Look, just edit your question with the code you're using now, and perhaps I (or someone else) can help you solve your problem. Anything else is just a waist of time.

Comment: No, don't update the code in my answer, update the code in your question!

Comment: I’ve edited the code, still gets the same error, I am using Dapper and SQLite Core.

Comment: The code you've posted in the question is a mess that wouldn't even compile. Please take the time to edit your question properly.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I am using my phone and I copies the code via the phone

Comment: Well, then, I'll guess you'll have to wait until you can get back to your computer and upload a proper code example.

Comment: `sReportNo = ReportNo,  sReportDate = ReportDate` is wrong. The names of the properties must match the names of the parameters

Comment: It’s matched, isn’t it?

Comment: No, the names of the parameters are `ReportNo` and `ReportDate` - not `sReportNo` and `sReportDate`

Comment: So I just need to replace between the names?

Comment: Should be `new {ReportNo = ?, ReportDate = ?}`, Where the `?` is replaced with the variables that contains the actual data

Comment: new {ReportNo = sReportNo, ReportDate = sReportDate}, correct?

Comment: Yes, assuming `sReportNo` and `sReportDate` are the names of your c# variables that contains the data.